# C# Desktop application - Update query from one table to another dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, linq, desktop

I am working on a c# .Net desktop application using IDE Visual Studio 2019.  I have two tables in SQLite, both having around 1 Million records each. I have to update a few columns of Table A from table B based on some matches. I have also loaded records in DATATABLES too for local processing.

Search and update field criteria vary from time to time, so I have to build dynamic queries.

I have records in tables as well as loaded in datatables. So any approach to update through direct table queries or local processing in DATATABLES is appreciated.

Followed below approaches :

Approach 1 using the query : Found on google search that We can update records from one table to another table easily by the single query in SQL but we can't update records from one table to another in SQLite. I had tried the query approach but failed later found that SQLite does not support.

I also tried to update records one by one in the loop, insert queries in the loop are very fast (took just 4-5 seconds for 200K records). But update query in the loop is very slow taking around 9 records per second. That will take hours to update all records.

Approach 2 using Linq  :

Schema of both tables are not the same but have links based on a few columns.

```
string field1 = "A";
string field2 = "B";


           var updateQuery = from r1 in table1Data.AsEnumerable()
                              join r2 in table2Data.AsEnumerable()
                              on r1.Field<string>(field1) equals r2.Field<string>(field2)
                              select new { r1, r2 };
```

This works fine for the single field but I need dynamic way and with multicolumn too (column count will be decided on run time based on user selection)

Comment: *but we can't update records from one table to another in SQLite* yes we can  ... search for `UPSERT` (requires SQLite >= 3.24.0)

Comment: Please share both tables with some sample data so that relevant query can be built.

Comment: Two Tables - Assume TableA  with 15 fields - all varchar type  and Table2 with 15 fields - all varchar type , schemas (field names) are different but may match on few field values ( fields to be compared and  fields to be updated are selected by user) so there are no fixed fields , that's why i need dynamic approach. Problem can be solved with either through single Update query in SQLite or Linq dynamic query.